# Javascript-reloading the page using AddEventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I want to use AddEventListener in javascript to reload the page when i press Enter(Like what F5 automatically do), and overall I want to know how to manipulate the shortcuts that being already defined in the computer(Like F5) using JavaScript.
thanks for help

I tried to use Addeventlistener but i couldn't specify it to reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
 if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      location.reload(true)
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "keyup," use the "keydown" event in the addEventListener. Each key has a unique "key code," for example, F5 is associated with the key code 116. Check the condition to determine whether the pressed key has a key code of 116 or not.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
           if(e.keycode === 116){
             location.reload(true);
           }
});
```